# Is there a way to use a reactive radio button value in a filter statement in the server

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm new to Shiny and R so don't overthink this.
Can I use the UI section of Shiny to FILTER a dataframe before passing it to `plot_ly`?

I'm trying to use a numeric value from a UI radio button choice ( say 1.75 ) in a data-frame filter statement preceeding a `plot_ly` command in the SERVER section

I can display the captured value in a `plot_ly` title just fine so I guess it's a character / string value, but variations on `as.numeric()` don't seem to help either.

I've tried :

```r
df2 <- filter(df,  price == input$radio )
#which fails with:
#Can't access reactive value 'gaspricer' outside of reactive consumer.
```

```r
reactive{{ df2 <- filter(df, price == as.number(input$radio) })
#which fails
```

or two stage:

```r
myvar <- some_function_of ( input$radio )    
df2 <- filter(df,  price == myvar )
#which also doesn't fool the interpreter
```

I'm wondering if I can make the dynamic interpreter happy somehow if I put the filtering inside the `plot_ly` statement, something like
`plotly( data = filter(df, ... ),   variables )`
(if that's even valid in R/plot_ly)
but then if I did that I can't figure out how to reference the new dataframe name which I need to dereference the selected column names for x and y variables,   such as `df[[input$xcol]]`
since `~[[input$xcol]]` doesn't seem to work.

Any cleverness would be appreciated. I'm out of my depth.

discussion:

I can use `reactive({...})` syntax, or `df[[input$myvar]]` type syntax to get a chosen dataframe field from a `selectInput()` statement into `plot_ly()` just fine.  That much works.   But outside the `plot_ly` statement, I'm running into problems.

What I would like to do now is use three radio-button groups in the UI section to pick three values to filter the dataframe before running plot_ly on it in the SERVER section.  If it were a single radio-button group maybe I could just pick which filter statement to use, I think but with several of them we're now up to 4x4x4 or more possible filter statements which is getting awkward.

Comment: Can you provide `ui` and `server` code required for the question to be completely reproducible along with necessary data if required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reproducible example/code for your error:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(
    inputId = "radio", 
    label = "Pick a value", 
    value = 6, 
    min = 3.5, 
    max = 8, 
    step = 0.1
  ), 
  
  tableOutput(outputId = "filtered")
  # <-- Yours is a plotOutput, I suppose --> #
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df2 <- dplyr::filter(iris, Sepal.Length == input$radio)
  
  output$filtered <- renderTable(df2())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```
Error : Can't access reactive value 'radio' outside of reactive consumer.
i Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observer()?
```

## Solution:

Make `df2` a reactive:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df2 <- reactive({
    dplyr::filter(iris, Sepal.Length <= input$radio)
  })
  
  output$filtered <- renderTable(df2())
}
```

## Explanation:

> To read from an input, you must be in a reactive context created by a function like `renderText()` or `reactive()`. 
>  ~ Mastering Shiny, Hadley Wickham.

Comment: Thanks, Mwavu.  I had tried putting reactive({ }) in various places but I guess not the right way.  I think I'd tried   reactive({ df2 <- etc }) which failed, but I'll do it the way you show and just put reactive ({ }) around the right side of the assignment.  Thank you!